# RefreshToken in blazor server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, blazor-server-side

Hello I implemented the remember Me in blazor
When the user connects the WEB API gives him a JWT and if he chose remember Me we generate the Refresh which will be put in a cookie in my front-end blazor application
Everything is going well
when my JWT has a duration of 30 minutes and 10 minutes before it expires I generate a new JWT thanks to the refreshToken in the cookie everything happens in my ApiService Service
but at some point my sessionStorage, my cookie and the database do not have the same refreshToken only the sessionStorage and the cookie keep the same value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehk5Y.png)
I have the impression that after the calls of my postAsJsonAsync
returns again to reexecute and we reach no other element

Comment: are your blazor on Azure under MSAL ?